# Ad hoc distribution add new device

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.forms, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to publish my app using ad hoc. And i was thinking about the 100 devices limitation.

Let's say I published my app for 20 users for example. And after some time a new user asks for my app.

What is the correct way to add him ?

-- If it's creating a new profile :

If I create a new ad hoc profile, what is gonna happen to the users using the old profile, will the app using the old profile stops working for them  or what exactly?

what about the limitation if the app will keep working, does that mean that we can create infinite ad hoc profiles and keep adding devices?

Comment: You have to know the UUID of the device if you want to create infinite ad hoc profiles and keep adding devices.

Comment: I don't get it, how can I use the UUID to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't affect the users with old profile.

Just add your new device and then go to your ad hoc profile and select all devices or the newly added device and then click generate and download and install the profile by double clicking it and do the routine [i.e., build & archive] again.

**Steps:**

**1.** Add the new UDID in Devices.

**2.** Select the Team Provisioning profile in Provisioning Profiles[i.e., Adhoc profile in your case].

**3.** Click the Edit button.

**4.** And under devices for that provisioning profile, click Select All, or just the devices you want included.

**5.** Click Generate.

Sometimes it takes a while before the certificate is updated and fetched from XCode.